# New Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: discussion, rpi

Ok, so who ordered the new Pico? How many did you order (I wish I had ordered more than 1 so I could try out the debugger)? What do you plan on doing with it?

Comment: @goldilocks one of the mods should create the pi-pico-pico tag to the main sight so it is consistent with the other tags, and before we have a multitude of variations. I believe pi-pico matches the current pattern pi-3 etc.

Comment: Micropython -- meh ;)

Comment: WRT a tag, you can't create one w/o a question.  This should be interesting, I imagine a brand new API and such.

Comment: @goldilocks yeah, arduino, adafruit etc. have already announced new boards using the new chip. I also saw the micro board in a pick and place SMD type reel. Wondering if a new pi will incorporate the new micro to provide analog etc. support.

Comment: I thought as a mod you could preemptively create a tag.

Comment: I've seen that reel too it's for when you get unattended access to the server room one night.  I guess it would be cool to have an MC integrated for real time physical stuff.  No more arduino sidecar.

Comment: You can't create a tag without a question because there is no mechanism to do so.  If you try to create one from the "Ask Question" page and never post/delete later the use count of the tag drops to zero and it disappears.  There are tags with no questions if you look at the end by popularity, but they are all synonyms.

Comment: @goldilocks Was stuck for a couple of hours on a missing module but managed to eventually found it and answered my own question. I tagged it with pi-pico and micropython. let the debate on whether the pico is on or off-topic begin.

Answer (score 2):

I have ordered a couple.

There is a SDK for C, but unfortunately it is in microscopic (8 pt) type, so I am unsure what it says.

I note the Comments on the Foundation Blog. People already complaining it doesn't have WiFi.

This reminds me of the hype when the Pi Zero was released - everyone was trying to add networking rather than using the device for its designed purpose.

Answer (score 0):

$4 is incredible considering that a similarly-spec'd Teensy 3 is $20. I wonder how long it will take till RP2040 gets support in major IDEs, such as Keil uVision. Arduino support [seems to be on  the way](https://blog.arduino.cc/2021/01/20/welcome-raspberry-pi-to-the-world-of-microcontrollers/) already.

Will definitely get myself one, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Arduino can sometimes take ages (we will have to see) but I am also waiting to see keil or mbed support. I would also like to see a tutorial with assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

I got 5 of them from Sparcfun, because they were available at the initial price of $4 each. Total prive was about $6, shipped. They're out of stock everywhere, and are showing up on EBAY for $15-20.

I don't have a specific use yet, but I'm sure I can find something to do with them. The only thing so far that I don't like about them is that they're wider that bthe Arduino NANO by about 0.100", or about 0.700" wide.

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120679/8697