# New Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W

Tags: discussion, rpi

Anyone thinking of picking up the new Zero 2 W? Any projects in mind if you have?

Here are the specs from the [product page](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-zero-2-w/):

- 1GHz quad-core 64-bit Arm Cortex-A53 CPU
- 512MB SDRAM
- 2.4GHz 802.11 b/g/n wireless LAN
- Bluetooth 4.2, Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE), onboard antenna
- Mini HDMI port and micro USB On-The-Go (OTG) port
- microSD card slot
- CSI-2 camera connector
- HAT-compatible 40-pin header footprint (unpopulated)
- H.264, MPEG-4 decode (1080p30); H.264 encode (1080p30)
- OpenGL ES 1.1, 2.0 graphics
- Micro USB power
- Composite video and reset pins via solder test points
- 65mm x 30mm

Comment: If this post is unwelcome feel free to close, I found [this one](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/new-raspberry-pi-pico) from the pico's announcement and thought it'd be fun to have a new one

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the same cheap rubbish with the same collection of unusual connectors which require adapters or non standard cables.

Seems to include the design flaws of its predecessor - vulnerable flimsy connectors hanging over the end of the board.

I wasted money on the Pi Zero W - won't be repeating the experience.
The 3A is similar and uses standard connectors.

Comment: Yeah, the compatibility (mostly useful for handheld emulators and stuff with custom accessories) is a double-edged sword. I'd rather one with USB-C and no usb ports so I could rely on a powered hub for however many full-sized ports I needed. And that mini HDMI... ️ a video-capable USB-C port would be more welcome

Answer (score 0):

The biggest upgrade looks like the cpu, going from a single core to four 64-bit cores. I like that they kept compatibility with the current version (even if I'd prefer USB-C).

I was working on an e-ink cyberdeck with the Zero W, but the performance just wasn't enough to make me happy. I think I'm going to buy one of these to test running the e-ink screen process (written in python) in another thread so I can do my emacs work on the primary thread.

So, not the biggest update, but it looks like a promising solution to a problem I had given up on!